# Tfs api for changeset details

Tags: api, tfs

I am working on a project using latest tfs api using .net client libraries to get the changeset details. But i am not able to do so. I can get the workitems details but not the changeset details like check in user, date etc. Is there any way to do this using c# code.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can use the API to query from TFS, following is my code:

You need to install the Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/).

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace _0914_GetChangesetDetails
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC"));
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Domain\user", "password");
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            int cid = vcs.GetLatestChangesetId();
            string path = "$/0418Scrum";
            var history = vcs.QueryHistory(path, RecursionType.Full, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Following are the latest 10 changeset in " + path + ":");

            foreach (Changeset item in history)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", item.ChangesetId, item.Owner, item.CreationDate, item.Comment);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The latest changeset ID is:" + cid);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]